# Is var always hoisted to the global execution context?

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code

```
var c=9;

function cb(){
  console.log(c);  // it prints undefined
  var c=0;
}

cb();  




var c=9;
    
    {
      console.log(c);  // it prints 9
      var c=0;
    }
```

So if I am not wrong does the var gets hoisted to the global execution context ??

Comment: No, that is not correct. A variable declared in a `var` declaration is hoisted to the top of the local function, or the top of the global scope (or module scope) if outside any function.

Comment: so where does the var c=0 ? gets hoisted in this case ,at the global scope right ? @Pointy

Comment: `var` is not scoped to simple `{}` blocks.

Comment: In which case? There are two in the code you posted. The second one, in the block, is hoisted to the global scope (and the `var` declaration is essentially ignored, because `c` is already declared).